# How to navigate to next view through only one section of the table?

Tags: ios4

I have one tableview having two sections. I want to navigate to next view by clicking on only one section. Other section should not go to the next page. 
can anyone please help me for this?

Answer (score 0):

In selection handler distinguish between those two cases, so you'll have something like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (indexPath.section == 0){
         //Some code to go to the next page
    } 
    else{
         // Some code not going to another page
    }
}
```

Comment: But that's not the code that handles cell selection, right? selectionStyle only sets the way selected cell is highlighted...